# Is there a way or a function to sort individual string elements in sql?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the below table:

| element | score |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 50 |
| BAC | 10 |
| CBA | 30 |
| XYZ | 115 |
| ZXY | 25 |

The SQL should give the following output. It should sort the element individually and then add up the values

| element | score |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 90 |
| XYZ | 140 |

I have used the below code to sort the elements: however this doesn't look very optimised. It would be better if there is a function to do this:

```
SELECT
    element,
    CONCAT_WS('', sorted_chars) AS sorted_input
FROM 
    (SELECT
         element,
         sort_array(collect_list(char), true) AS sorted_chars
     FROM 
         (SELECT
              element,
              explode(split(element, '')) AS char
          FROM 
              table) t
     GROUP BY 
         element) t
```

Comment: `mysql` and `postgresql` are two different databases. Please only use the on that your are actually using.

Comment: neither of mysql and postgresql have operators like "*sort_array*", "*collect_list*", "*explode*" and "*split*": this looks some kind of pseudo-code algorithm or something related

Comment: @lemon - Looks like [Spark SQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

A solution (for MySQL), for MSSQL see note below, in steps:

First split the `ABC` (or `BAC`) to individual letters:

```
-- split the strings (currently fixed to max 3 positions...)
SELECT 
  element,
  score,
  x,
  substring(element,x,1) as Y
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 as x union all select 2 union all select 3) x
```

output:

| element | score | x | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 50 | 3 | C |
| ABC | 50 | 2 | B |
| ABC | 50 | 1 | A |
| BAC | 10 | 3 | C |
| BAC | 10 | 2 | A |
| etc. |  |  |  |

Then create `element_new`

```
-- create element_new
SELECT 
  element,
  score,
  GROUP_CONCAT(y  order by y SEPARATOR '') as element_new
FROM (
  SELECT 
  element,
  score,
  x,
  substring(element,x,1) as Y
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 as x union all select 2 union all select 3) x
) Y
GROUP BY element,score;
```

Last step, group on `element_new`:

```
SELECT 
   element_new,
   sum(score) as score
FROM (
  SELECT 
    element,
    score,
    GROUP_CONCAT(y  order by y SEPARATOR '') as element_new
  FROM (
    SELECT 
    element,
    score,
    x,
    substring(element,x,1) as Y
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 as x union all select 2 union all select 3) x
  ) Y
  GROUP BY element,score  
) z
GROUP BY element_new;
```

output:

| element_new | score |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 90 |
| XYZ | 140 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/lgNFtICm)

EDIT:

For MSSQL only the `GROUP_CONCAT()` need to be changed to `STRING_AGG()`.  see: [DBFIDDLE for MSSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/x8p1b-p_)